# Put a category of column's non-null count as a separate column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I have to first calculate the number of values in a column (include duplicates too). After that I have to assign a pool range.

Example pool ranges: (1000-3000), (3001-7000), (7001-20000), (20001-500000).

Suppose we get the count of total number of values as 4500 in column A and 8500 in column B. 4500 will be in range (3001-7000) and 8500 in (7001-20000).

There are columns C and D in which I have to return this range value. Column C contains information for column A, so column C will populate with values (3001-7000). Similarly, column D contains information for column B, so column D will populate with values (7001-2000). How can we achieve this in PySpark?

[image]

Comment: - How do you determine pool ranges,? Is it stored in any table? - Will column C and column D have same data across the column?- Kindly provide your attempt and challenges faced.

Comment: Hi @Aswin i have already mentioned in question  that Column C will store pool range for column A and column D store for  column B. All these 4 columns are in same table.                    Pool ranges we can give depending on the requirement . We can give pool ranges in different table also.       Coming to your second questions please refer the SS that i have pasted

Comment: But the challenge here is we first need to get total count of column and put the pool range value in its relative column. I hope it will help you in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting the non-null values is easy in Spark (`df.summary("count")`), but you will need to provide the pool ranges somehow. In the following example I provided pool ranges as a list of lists (one: 1 -> 2, another: 3 -> 10).

Inputs:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1111, 2222),
     (1111, None),
     (1111, None),
     (None, None)],
    ["col1", "col2"])

ranges = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 10]
]
```

Script:

```py
cols = ["col1", "col2"]
df = df.replace("", None)
summary = df.agg(*[F.count(c).alias(c) for c in cols]).head().asDict()
col_rng = {}
for c, cnt in summary.items():
    for r in ranges:
        if r[1] >= int(cnt):
            col_rng[c] = f"{r[0]}->{r[1]}"
            break

df = df.withColumn("range_col1", F.lit(col_rng["col1"]))
df = df.withColumn("range_col2", F.lit(col_rng["col2"]))

df.show()
# +----+----+----------+----------+
# |col1|col2|range_col1|range_col2|
# +----+----+----------+----------+
# |1111|2222|     3->10|      1->2|
# |1111|null|     3->10|      1->2|
# |1111|null|     3->10|      1->2|
# |null|null|     3->10|      1->2|
# +----+----+----------+----------+
```